# Unable to display iframe in ms teams chat

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an use case which bot needs to send iframe as response, I'm able to send iframe but bot message body showing empty.

Is there any way to show iframe content in Microsoft Teams?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not 100% standard use of them, you can use a [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) for this. There are various ways to launch them, and one way is via a button in an [Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards). It's a bit of work learning each of these topics, if you haven't used them before, but it's certainly possible to use the to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have gone through the task module docs and that is what i'm looking, Thank you

Comment: glad to hear. Good luck with it and just ask any questions here if you run into issues

Comment: i have followed the instructions as per the docs, able to send initial cad but when i click on button, it's opening popup but the body is empty

Comment: That sounds like you're missing a "Valid Domains" entry for your domain that the popup is coming from...

Comment: when i upload manifest in teams with valid domains it us working as expected but with azure web app bot getting the same issue, and i'm unable to find manifest file in web app bot deployment code

Comment: there's an option to download the source for the project, for a web app bot - it would be in there I think.